# fix progress bar in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

The problem is the label gets displayed before the `progress-bar` is completed.  How do I make the `label` display only after the `progress-bar` is fully complete?

I tried changing the max values to a higher number but it didn't work.

```
public partial class dload : Form
{
    public dload()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dload_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 5000;
        for (i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
            if (i == 5000)
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, your loop will only run to 5000. You don't need the `if` inside the loop. Remove the while clause and only put `label1.Visible = true;` underneath the loop. Now, in your case, the progressbar completed, but the UI did not quite update it yet. I think you could put `progressBar1.Refresh()` after you update the value. _edit_ Just ran this code and saw what you mean. This is strange. Need to investigate and come back to you

Comment: Why don't you set 'label1.Visible = true;' after the 'for' loop?

Comment: You don't need the if statement. Just move the label1.Visible to after the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Your code run very vast, it is about less than a second to set value from 0% to 100% ! But 
`ProgressBar` has two styles for displaying the current status (`Classic` and `Continues`).

In `Continues` mode if the progress value went to 100% from 0% the control will show an animation, which is not display the real and accurate progress. You can set a delay via `Thread.Sleep()` and show your label immediately after the for loop to find out to what i happening !

The Below code will work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 5000;
    for (i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        progressBar1.Value = i;

    }
    label1.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an animation problem.  A "hack" around it is to actually decrease the progress value by 1:

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
progressBar1.Maximum = 5000;
for (int i = 0; i < progressBar1.Maximum; i++) {
  progressBar1.Value = i;
  progressBar1.Value = Math.Max(i - 1, progressBar1.Minimum);
}
label1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

use `progressBar1.Refresh`:

```
public partial class dload : Form
{
    public dload()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void dload_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visible = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 5000;
    for (i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = i;
        progressBar1.Refresh();
        if (i == 5000)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```